# Do filepond support files contain geoJson extension. if yes how to apply?

Tags: rxjs, angular6, filepond

i have set up a filepond for which accepted types are json and csv. if i want geojson filetypes to be accepted what should i do?

fileUploadOptions = {
    class: 'static-filepond',
    multiple: false,
    labelIdle: this.translation.translate('Drop files here'),
    acceptedFileTypes: 'text/csv, application/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/json, text/tab-separated-values'
  };

when i m uploading geojson file it is showing invalid type. i want geojson file to be accepted and show the preview in the format of json

Answer (score 0):

Drop your file in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/NzRvbj) to find out its mime type, then you can add the mime type to the list of `acceptedFileTypes`. Note that mime types might differ across browsers so best to check in a couple.

Comment: Thanks, but i m not getting the mime type when I upload .geojson extended file

Comment: In that case the browser does not know the mime type, you can then implement the `fileValidateTypeDetectType` method to manually supply a type. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/

Comment: Can you please help me how to implement fileValidateTypeDetectType method